# Google chart show visualization out of form input

Tags: php, mysql, date, checkbox, google-visualization

I am actually working on a project to visualize measurement values. Right know I had the ability  to visualize all the values from the database, but going further to make it possible to use checkbox so it will be easier to choose what the user want to see. I am stuck how to make it possible for the user to firstly use checkbox, one solution was to make many if for each of the checkbox and them together if one or more as checked.

Things i need help with:

- Giving the user opportunity to choose what they want to see out of the checkbox.
- Sort data out of date and time.

This is the goal:

[image]

So far have I came:

[image]

Code:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysql_select_db("chart", $con);

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM googlechart");

$rows = array();
//flag is not needed
$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

 // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles
    // Note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage and string will be used for column title
    array('label' => 'Time',    'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'PH',      'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'temperature','type' => 'number'), 
    array('label' => 'Chlorine','type' => 'number') );

    $rows = array();

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
     $temp = array();
        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Time']); 
        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['PH']);
        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['temperature']);
        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Chlorine']);

        $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Time']); 
        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);

}

 $table['rows'] = $rows;
 $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
 echo $jsonTable;   

?>


<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);

        var options = {
        /*width: 900, height: 900, */
          title: 'Visualization',
          /* curveType: 'function', */
           legend: { position: 'bottom' },
           pointSize: 10,
        vAxis: {title: "Values", titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        hAxis: {title: "Time", titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);


      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Phpmyadmin:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can always sanitize your `DataTable` by using [`removeColumn`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_removeColumn). You dont have a fiddle nor give example of the JSON, so here is an example with some other values - but the technique is very simple.

Suppose you have 3 rows with data : `Cats`, `blanket1` and `blanket2`. Then implement checkboxes for each data column :

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cats" checked="checked">
<label for="cats">cats</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="blanket1" checked="checked">
<label for="blanket1">blanket2</label>
...
```

In your `drawChart` method, examine the checked state for each checkbox and remove the corresponding data column if it is not :

```js
//remember reverse order!
if (!blanket2.checked) data.removeColumn(3);    
if (!blanket1.checked) data.removeColumn(2)
...
```

Reverse order is nessecary, you have to check for the last column first, then the second last column and so on.

Finally, assign a click handler to each checkbox, redrawing the chart each time a checkbox is clicked  :

```js
cats.onchange = drawChart;
blanket1.onchange = drawChart;
...
```

See demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/rJHtA/**

Off course - in your case I would not ruin the original `<?=$jsonTable?>` each and every time.  Hold the original `<?=$jsonTable?>` in a global variable and create the chart out of a local copy of that.

To order data by date (time) you must reload the page or use AJAX to get a new `<?=$jsonTable?>`. This should not be done along with the show / hide of the columns (no need to reload data you allready have). It is impossible to deliver a concrete example since you are not telling how the dates are inputted in the (supposed) form, how you intend to process the PHP or even what format `time` has in the table. Is it strings? We dont know. But assuming you have two `<input>`'s on a form, and `Date` is of type `DATE` :

```
<input type="text" name="from">
<input type="text" name="to">
```

Then on the server :

```
$SQL = 'SELECT * FROM googlechart '.
       'WHERE `Date` BETWEEN "'.$_GET['from'].'" AND "'.$_GET['to'].'"';
$sth = mysql_query($SQL);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I am saving date as: YYYY-MM-DD as the property in phpmyadmin for date. The other I want to ask you is in the X axse I only show time, but when you do measurement for long periods, many weeks. It should be best to give the user oppurtunity to see the date also in the X axse. How do you think that wil be solved best? I made a example of I think will be the best way: https://www.dropbox.com/s/emepuay8263e9pw/date.png
The other way is to have date with each of the time numbers. The best way I think is to distinguish the measurement for each day from the others day.

Comment: Made a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451276/google-chart-timeline-with-date-in-x-axis

Comment: Be careful with `removeColumn`, as you actually lose the data if you use that.  Better would be to use a DataView and specify which columns you want to see.

Comment: Hey @asgallant, see my comment to that -> "**in your case I would not ruin the original <?=$jsonTable?> each and every time**", but you are right. off course - Perhaps I should have been clearer on that, and given an example how to hold an original reuseable JSON source.

Comment: I updated your example to use a view instead: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/rJHtA/3/.  I missed that you were calling `drawChart` in the event handlers for the checkboxes, so the danger in my original comment was overstated in this case.  Still, better to use the view from a resources and execution standpoint.

Comment: @asgallant, great! But I think OP has "come further", he wanted a complete solution for needs he didnt have tried to solve - the "I want to.."-image is great though :) And you are - again - right. A DataView  is the "correct" solution.