# Google chart timeline with date in x axis

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, date, google-visualization

Working on a google line chart. The problem I have came into is that the chart on shows values of one day, have not implemented timeline with dates. I understand that the chart will be wide if your getting values from for example one week, is there any way to solve that ? I was thinking of something like this ?

[image]

How its looking right now:

[image]

Database: ( the date is saved as date in phpadmin)

[image]

Code:

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysql_select_db("chart", $con);

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM googlechart");

$rows = array();
//flag is not needed
$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

 // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles
    // Note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage and string will be used for column title
    array('label' => 'Time',    'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'PH',      'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'temperature','type' => 'number'), 
    array('label' => 'Chlorine','type' => 'number'),

    );

    $rows = array();

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
     $temp = array();
        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Time']); 
        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['PH']);
        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['temperature']);
        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Chlorine']);


        $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Time']);   
        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);

}

 $table['rows'] = $rows;
 $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
 echo $jsonTable;   

?>


<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);

        var options = {
        /*width: 900, height: 900, */
          title: 'Visualization',
          /* curveType: 'function', */
           legend: { position: 'bottom' },
           pointSize: 10,
        vAxis: {title: "Values", titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        hAxis: {title: "Time", titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);


      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get part of what you want using `format` property of `hAxis`, for example:

```
hAxis: {
    format: "HH:mm",
    ...
}
```

See line chart [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options) for `hAxis.format`.

**Update:** [Example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yaqew/1/edit)

Comment: You are using timedate, is this possible with date and time ? (two different column)

Comment: You have to combine data and time together into one column if you want to use both for your axis values.  You can either do this when you pull the data from your database, or via a DataView in javascript.